# pythonic way to count total number of letters in string in python

Tags: python, string, methods

I just started learning python, and I can think of two ways to count letters in a string (ignoring numbers, punctuation, and white spaces)

1. Using for loop:

```
for c in s:
    if c.isalpha():
        counter += 1
print(counter)
```

2. Create a list of alphabets and count the length of the list: (It will create an unwanted list)

```
import re
s = "Nice. To. Meet. You."
letters = re.findall("([a-z]|[A-Z])", s)
counter = len(letters)
print(counter)
```

Can anyone tell me is there a "pythonic" way to achieve the same result?
like single line code or a function called that will return an int which is the answer?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first approach is perfectly pythonic, and probably the way to go. You could slightly simplify, using `filter` or a list comprehension as:

```
s = "Nice. To. Meet. You."
len(list(filter(str.isalpha, s)))
# 13
```

Or:

```
len([i for i in s if i.isalpha()])
# 13
```

Your second approach isn't really advisable, since you don't really need to use a regex for this. Note that you could simplify that pattern to `([a-zA-Z])`, by the way.

Comment: So as far as i understand, there are no method or function that we could call? like: xxxx(s) which return an int?

Comment: What do you mean? There is `i.isalpha()` but you have to apply it on every character @heihei

Comment: Sorry, I miss that line, i think `len([i for i in s if i.isalpha()])` is already the best way. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to remove anything that is not a letter and then count the length of the string:

```py
import re
s = "Nice. To. Meet. You."
counter = len(re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]','',s))
```

Comment: @JvdV, thanks for that! I updated my answer to only use alphabets

Comment: Thank you, another neat way!!

Answer (score 0):

Using regex (`re`), you can find all letters and count their occurrence:

```
len(re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z]", string))
```